# Difference between xs and xsd in XML schema file?

Tags: xml, data-structures, xsd

What is the difference between the `xs` and `xsd` prefixes in XML schema files?

Comment: it's just a XML namespace prefix for the XML schema namespaces, which you can basically choose as you wish - xs and xsd are just the most commonly used ones

Answer (score 117):

From [the XSD 1.0 spec on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions):

> The XML representation of schema
>   components uses a vocabulary
>   identified by the namespace name
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema. For
>   brevity, the text and examples in this
>   specification use the prefix xs: to
>   stand for this namespace; in practice,
>   any prefix can be used.

in the end **xs** or **xsd** are only prefixes. XSD is used for example more by Microsoft schemas.

The important is how you declare the namespace.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  ...
</xs:schema>
```

or

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  ...
</xsd:schema>
```

should be equivalent.

Comment: So the short answer is, there is no difference?

Comment: nope ! Took me a while to get this sorted out - not just `xs`/`xsd` - but in general how XML Schemas work. Also, got to know the difference between DTD and XSD.

Answer (score 20):

There is **no difference**, it is just a matter of choice

Answer (score 12):

The `xs:` and `xsd:` are called namespace prefixes. They are declared using `xmlns` elements in the root element.

By convention people tend to choose either `xs:` or `xsd:` and map that to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. Having both in a single document is confusing and should be avoided.

Check your `xmlns` declarations to determine what the namespaces are.